# What is causing my label's event handler to fire twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What happens:

Clicking the checkbox causes the code to fire once (as expected).
Clicking the *label* causes the code to fire twice.

The code:

```js
function ToggleVisibility(ctl) {
  console.info($(ctl).css("background-color"));
  var backgroundColor = $(ctl).css('background-color') === 'rgb(255, 255, 255)' ? 'rgb(255, 165, 0)' : 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
  console.info(backgroundColor);
  $(ctl).css("background-color",
    backgroundColor);
  console.info($(ctl).css("background-color"));
  console.debug($(ctl));
  console.info("****");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divTemplate">
  <label onclick="ToggleVisibility(this)" style="background-color: white;"><input type="checkbox" /><span>Checkbox item</span></label>
</div>
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Checkbox is inside label so when you click on checkbox it will consider as label click

Comment: Whoa...that's... weird but moving the handler to the checkbox fixes it. Pop that as an answer, yeah?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `event.preventDefault();` to the start of the event handler.